# How negate value of Boolean option in package using kvoptions

Tags: package-options, kvoptions

In the package created by the following source, how can one change the value of `\optB` to `true` if `\optA` is true — so that the message written to the log would become `>>> optB is true` even though the option `\optB=false` had been passed to the package, as shown (but `optA=true` had been passed, as shown).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mypkg.sty}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=MY,prefix=MY@}
\DeclareBoolOption{optA}
\DeclareBoolOption{optB}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
% what code here to switch value of optB *if* optA is true?
\ifMY@optB \typeout{>>> optB is true} \else \typeout{>>> optB is false}\fi
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[optA=true,optB=false]{mypkg}
\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each Boolean option three commands are created:

- `\if<prefix><option name>` which acts as one of TeX's conditional commands,
- `\<prefix><option name>true` to enable the option, and
- `\<prefix><option name>false` to disable the option.

Based on these commands, you can easily define custom conditions to override the values passed from the user (after the `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` call). In your case it's simply:

```
\ifMY@optA
    \MY@optBtrue
\fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, not just the method. The explanation fleshes out, and puts together, the terse information in the `kvoptions` documentation (in section 2.2.2, where it says, for a boolean option `verbose`, that the corresponding switch is initialized as `\foobar@verbosefalse`; and the "Summary of internal macros" section 2.4, where it lists `\if<prefix><key>true` and  `\if<prefix><key>false` to enable & disable the switch, respectively.