# Package minted Warning: Unexpected value for option `chapter'(minted) is ignored on input line 77

Tags: compiling, minted, warnings, kvoptions, abntex2

I am importing `minted` like this:

```latex
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,twoside,chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE,]{abntex2}
\usepackage[newfloat,chapter,outputdir=setup/cache]{minted}

\begin{document}
Hi.
\end{document}
```

And when running it:

```
[no file]:77: Package minted Warning: Unexpected value for option `chapter'(minted) is ignored on input line 77.
[no file]:77: Package minted Warning: Unexpected value for option `section'(minted) is ignored on input line 77.
```

This warning is coming from the package `kvoptions.sty`:

```
File: latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
409:     {#1}{%
410:       Unexpected value for option `#3'\MessageBreak
411:       is ignored%
412:     }%
413:   \fi
```

As you see, my document class `abntex2` takes in the options `chapter` and `section`, which `minted` is trying to process for himself.

How can I fix this warning? (I mean, get rid of it, (it is the last one on my thesis))

Related:

1. [Warning when adding package minted?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380799/warning-when-adding-package-minted)
2. [How negate value of Boolean option in package using kvoptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499937/how-negate-value-of-boolean-option-in-package-using-kvoptions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top line defines `chapter=TITLE` as a global option, which so is passed to *every* loaded package.

Since `minted` has `chapter` declared with `\DeclareVoidOption`, `kvoptions` warns about it having a value, at the moment the option is passed to the package, which happens before the explicit options are evaluated. The warning about `chapter` is innocuous, but the one about `section` isn't, because `minted` thinks that you have passed the `section` option, which is not what you want.

The only workaround I see is to remove the offending options from the list of global options before loading `minted`.

```latex
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,twoside,chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE,]{abntex2}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\def\x#1chapter=TITLE,#2\@nil{%
  \endgroup\def\@classoptionslist{#1#2}%
}\expandafter\x\@classoptionslist\@nil
\begingroup
\def\x#1section=TITLE,#2\@nil{%
  \endgroup\def\@classoptionslist{#1#2}%
}\expandafter\x\@classoptionslist\@nil
\makeatother

\usepackage[newfloat,chapter,outputdir=setup/cache]{minted}

\begin{document}
Hi.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I load `\usepackage{datetime}` before you using your fix, i.e., right after `documentclass`, latex throw this error: `Runaway argument? english,12pt,a4paper,twoside,\@nil \begingroup \def \x ##1section=TIT\ETC. test2.tex:16: Paragraph ended before \x was complete`

Comment: If I removed the fix, then, the two warnings keep popping up. Instead, I kept your fix, while I imported the `datetime` package after including the minted package, and the error was gone.

Comment: @user I guess this has to do with the fact that `datetime` loads `xkeyval`, which plays with `\@classoptions`. So yes, the fix should be before loading `datetime`.

Comment: When I do not add the arguments `chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE` to my class, your code throw errors. Can you make it not throw errors when I am not passing the `chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE` arguments to my class?

Comment: I managed to do it and posted it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

After finding [testing for a documentclass option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110292/testing-for-a-documentclass-option) I managed to fix the error throw when the options `chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE` are not passed to the class:

```latex
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,twoside,chapter=TITLE,section=TITLE,]{abntex2}

\makeatletter
  \@ifclasswith{abntex2}{chapter=TITLE}{
    \begingroup
    \def\x#1chapter=TITLE,#2\@nil{%
      \endgroup\def\@classoptionslist{#1#2}%
    }\expandafter\x\@classoptionslist\@nil
  }{}

  \@ifclasswith{abntex2}{section=TITLE}{
    \begingroup
    \def\x#1section=TITLE,#2\@nil{%
      \endgroup\def\@classoptionslist{#1#2}%
    }\expandafter\x\@classoptionslist\@nil
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage[newfloat,chapter,outputdir=setup/cache]{minted}

\begin{document}
Hi.
\end{document}
```